# Unificar consultas de un cursor Sql Server

Tags: sql-server

Estoy tratando de crear un reporte de mis sucursales con un cursor
Y estoy buscando la manera de que muestre todas las consultas que arroja como si fuera una sola consulta.

Este es un ejemplo

```
    DECLARE @Suc VARCHAR(30);

DECLARE CursorUno CURSOR FOR 
SELECT Sucursal FROM Corp.dbo.Sucursales ORDER BY Num_Sucursal; 

OPEN CursorUno 
    FETCH NEXT FROM CursorUno INTO @Suc

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
        DECLARE @SQLString1 varchar(MAX);
     SET @SQLString1=
     N'
        SELECT Sucursal, Num_Sucursal, Cliente FROM '+@Suc+'.dbo.Clientes
      '
      EXECUTE(@SQLString1)
        FETCH NEXT FROM CursorUno INTO @Suc
    END 

CLOSE CursorUno 
DEALLOCATE CursorUno
```

¿Es posible hacer esto?
¿Tienen alguna forma de hacerlo?

De antemano Gracias!!!

Comment: Primero que nada: ¿Por que un cursor? segundo, ¿podrías poner un ejemplo de tu consulta? no es lo mismo si se trata de un `select` o una llamada a un sp. De todas formas, se puede, habría que ir insertando   en una tabla temporal

Comment: @PatricioMoracho gracias por comentar,  te comento cada una de las sucursales es una base de datos entonces necesito extraer información de dicha sucursal y el cursor lo estoy usando para que haga el recorrido de cada nombre de BD ya que estos los extraigo de otra Base de datos en una tabla SUCURSALES y asi es como puedo hacer los JOINS entre Bases de datos ya que todas las Bd son iguales, solo cambian los nombres. El detalle esta en que los resultados arrojados son correctos solo que estan divididos entre cada sucursal como si hiciera 10 consultas y  necesito es que se vea como si fuera 1

Comment: @PatricioMoracho ya añadí un ejemplo

Comment: Esto el algo productivo? porque suena a un diseño no del todo correcto... no @PatricioMoracho??

Comment: Clientes exclusivos de cada sucursal, es raro, normalmente un cliente debería serlo de toda la empresa, pero tal vez tengan alguna razón para resolverlo de esta forma @gbianchi

Comment: @PatricioMoracho Muchísimas gracias tu respuesta me fue de mucha ayuda, me ha funciono muy bien, Gracias Saludos!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como ya te mencionaron, no es una idea muy práctica tener las sucursales divididas en bases independientes, podría ser hasta cierto punto entendible si se tratase de bases locales consolidadas que vienen de sucursales que no tienen conectividad con una casa central. **Si se tratase de un ejercicio deberías revisar el diseño que estás haciendo**. De cualquier manera el problema está y se puede resolver, aunque tiene costos por hacerlo de esta forma: 1) lógica más compleja y fuera de lo "natural" del lenguaje SQL 2) Dificultad del Motor de BD para poder aplicar optimizaciones 3) Posibilidad de sufrir una inyección SQL (en tu caso si no tienes bien controlado el valor de `Sucursal`)

Una posibilidad, así como estás escribiendo una sentencia dinámica y ejecutándola por cada base, bien podrías escribir otra dónde a cada base se le aplica un `UNION ALL` y al finalizar el ciclo terminas ejecutando la sentencia completa:

```
DECLARE @Suc VARCHAR(30);
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @SQL = ''

DECLARE CursorUno CURSOR FOR 
SELECT Sucursal FROM Corp.dbo.Sucursales ORDER BY Num_Sucursal; 

OPEN CursorUno 
    FETCH NEXT FROM CursorUno INTO @Suc

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
        SET @SQL = @SQL + N'SELECT Sucursal, Num_Sucursal, Cliente FROM '+@Suc+'.dbo.Clientes UNION ALL '
    FETCH NEXT FROM CursorUno INTO @Suc
    END 

CLOSE CursorUno 
DEALLOCATE CursorUno

-- Esto es para quitar el ultimo UNION ALL (revisalo)
SET @SQL = SUBSTRING(@SQL, 1, LEN(@SQL) - 11)

-- Este print es para revisar la sentencia final
-- y ajustarla eventualmente
PRINT(@SQL)

-- Descomenta esta línea si la sentencia es correcta
--EXECUTE(@SQL)
```

Comment: No soy el autor de la pregunta pero que buena respuesta.